Auto-include webpack vendors bundles
I'm using webpack's CodeSplittingPlugin which produces vendors bundles, is there a way to prevent the need to manually add and update vendor bundles script tags in HTML? Something like a bundle that has a static name and that I can add to all of my HTML documents which will auto load the vendor bundle for scripts that require it?
I don't want to use the HTMLWebpackPlugin because I'm using Razor views and not plain HTML.
